# Adminhtml how to get current scope in ajax controller

Tags: magento2

I need following if in admin i click on button i need to write some system values based on the current scope.

```
/** @var \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $resourceConfig */
$resourceConfig->saveConfig('path/to/field', $value, $scope, $scopeId);
```

so the question is how to get the scope?

Answer (score 0):

fixed issue by adding some parameters in to javascript call, basicaly we check if in admin url we have either store or website parameter and passing it to the script.

```
var a = window.location.pathname.split('/');
if(a.indexOf('website') !== -1){
    a.splice(0, a.indexOf('website'));
    params = {
        'website': a[1]
    };
} else {
    if(a.indexOf('store') !== -1){
        a.splice(0, a.indexOf('store'));
        params = {
            'store': a[1]
        };
    } else {
        params = {
        };
    }
}
new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>', {
    loaderArea:     false,
    asynchronous:   true,
    parameters:     params,
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
         var response = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);
    }
});
```

also rewrited part of the save function, it seem the first method didn't save the config value directly but only after you click save manually.

```
\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
\Magento\Config\Model\Config\Factory $configFactory
...
$this->_configFactory = $configFactory;
$this->_request = $request;
...
$configData = [
    'section' => 'path',
    'website' => ($this->_request->getParam('website', 0) ? $this->_request->getParam('website', 0):null),
    'store'   => ($this->_request->getParam('store', 0) ? $this->_request->getParam('store', 0) : null),
    'groups'  => [
        'to' => [
            'fields' => [
                'field' => [
                    'value' => $value,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
/** @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config $configModel */
$configModel = $this->_configFactory->create(['data' => $configData]);
$configModel->save();
```

now this saves value based on website / store view